# Load images from libraries referenced as .dll files

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

I'm doing research and prototyping at my internship, and my topic is whether it's possible to use a Blazor library compiled as a dll (as opposed to referencing the library as a project).

Specifically I am meant to focus on content such as css and images, which seems to be a problem when accessing from a dll in general.

My structure is as follows:

SampleApp references SampleLibrary, which has an image in its content folder. The image is set to be an embedded resource, so it should be included in the dll.

I'm now trying to access the file via img-tag, but I can't find a way to give a correct path to reference in the SampleApp, let alone the SampleLibrary itself.

Did anyone find a way to reference image paths from dlls like that?

Answer (score 1):

Create a Blazor class library (dotnet new blazorlib) including your resources, which allows you to share the code in a NuGet package.
The Blazor class library handles embedding the image resources in the built assembly. The image files are placed in the wwwroot folder, and the tooling takes care of embedding the resources when the library is built.
The built NuGet package is referenced in the project file of a Blazor app just as any normal NuGet package is referenced. After the app has been restored, app code can reference the image files...

Hope this helps...